# Color equality in javascript

Tags: javascript, css, colors

Is there a way to check if two strings representing colors are equal, whether they are hex, rgb, rgba, or in word form.

For example, these would be equal

"red" and "#ff0000" 
"red" and "#f00" 
"red" and "rgb(255, 0, 0)" 
"#ff0000" and "rgba(255, 0, 0, 255)"

What I'm trying to do is join two or more elements together if their colors are the same, but sometimes the colors are represented differently.

I was checking the string equality of element.style.color, but then I ran into this problem. Would I be better off with a different approach?

A side question, and just out of curiosity, is does one browsers "dark blue" rgb value equal another browsers "dark blue" rgb value, for all colors?

Comment: If you call .css() with jQuery you can get the rgb(r,g,b) value back out of it.

Comment: You also can use `getComputedStyle(el).backgroundColor` :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Tiny color

https://bgrins.github.io/TinyColor/

https://bgrins.github.io/TinyColor/tinycolor.js

you just need to pass the color name and it will return the color name in  hex, rgb etc.

```
var tiny = tinycolor(color);
var hexString=  tiny.toHexString();
var hex8String=  tiny. tiny.toHex8String();
```

and there are other similar methods

```
tiny.toRgbString()
tiny.toHslString()
tiny.toHsvString()
tiny.toName()
tiny.getFormat()
```

once you got all format, Then you can compare using string equality. 
Please check the demo given it above link.

There is one method also which compare colors

```
tinycolor.equals(color1, color2)
```

Answer (score 4):

`window.getComputedStyle(el).backgroundColor` returns a color in `rgb(r, g, b)` format.

You can also use `jQuery.css()` for get it.

About color aliases: There are lot of [cross-browser safe colors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_colorsfull.asp), but you may be can't rely to it, I'm not sure about IE :)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It's always better to have an option that doesn't require pulling in an entirely new library.